# get the index of first element to mach a condition in an XMLListCollection Object

Tags: xml, apache-flex, actionscript, e4x, xmllist

I have an XMLListCollection object that contains items with an ID property. I want to find one particular item by id and then get it's index in the collection.
This is done to be able to tell the comboBox (whose dataProvider is the XMLListCollection) the index of the item to display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this works: (replace 'item' with the appropriate tag name).

```
comboBox.selectedItem = XML(xmlListCol.source.item.(@id == requiredIndex));
```

If not, use this:

```
var list:XMLList = xmlListCol.source;
var index:Number = -1;
for(i = 0; i < list.length(); i++)
  if(XML(list[i]).@id == requiredID)
  {
    index = i;
    break;
  }
if(index != -1)
  comboBox.selectedIndex = index;
else
  //deal with it
```

Comment: The top didnt work, but the buttom worked a little better for me though I had to tweek it. 

Thanks!